# nested std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

is it possible to have a `std::function` return an `std::function` and use various functions recursive with other std::functions, say a function of a function? In other words I want to collapse an array of functions into a single function.

for example going off basic tutorials

```
double genFunc(double x, std::function<double (double x)>f)
{
    double res = f(x);
    return res;
}

double square(double x){
    return x * x;
}

double dbl_sq(double x){
    return square(x * x);
}
```

How can i modify this to allow for nested `std::function<std::function>` calls?

Comment: i think your question got cut off near the bottom.

Comment: Sure... for example: `std::function<int()> bindVal(std::function<int(int)> f, int v) { return [=]{return f(v);}; }`... what issues are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but I'll take a stab at it.

So, you want a `std::function` that's nested, but calls all of the elements in one call? That would mean you could do several things, but the simplest would be, something like this:

```
std::function<double(double)> nest(const std::function<double(double)> functions[], const int count) {
    if (count == 1) {
        return functions[0];
    }

    return [=](double input) {
        return nest(functions + 1, count - 1)(functions[0](input));
    };
}

int main()
{
    static const auto sq = [](double input) {
        return input * input;
    };

    static const auto dbl_sq = [](double input) {
        return sq(input * input);
    };

    static const auto dbl = [](double input) {
        return input * 2;
    };

    static const std::function<double(double)> sqrt = ::sqrt;

    // now lets construct a 'nested lambda'
    static const std::function<double(double)> funcs[] = {
        sq, dbl, sqrt
    };

    static const std::function<double(double)> func = nest(funcs, 3);

    std::cout << func(4) << std::endl;  // 5.65685
    std::cout << ::sqrt((4 * 4) * 2) << std::endl; // 5.65685
}
```

Which simply 'collapses' an array of functions into a single function.

If this isn't what you are requesting, then please edit your original question to make it more clear what you wish to accomplish.